# show different views for different users with different permissions

Tags: php, templates, permissions, view, symfony-1.4

i'm developing a social net like website and i have some trouble in how to manage views for different kind of users. i have several pages that it's content and resulting views depends on the users permissions.
for example if user is a member of a group(has membership credential) can see so many things in that group page , but if he is not, the template should be so many different.

the simplest way is to control each part of the page with IF structure . but it's kind of nasty and i don't like it.

do you have any better idea or ifs are best solutions for these kind of situations.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on how you **would** like to create your templates. :-)

1. Combine slots, partials and components. This is probably the easiest and most 'readable' solution. It separates the logic in easy reusable blocks.
2. You could create seperate layouts, and call `<?php decorate_with('template_user'); ?>` in your template (add the `if`-statements to a partial and include the partial)
3. or create your own base actions class, which in the `preExecute()` sets the template (`this->setLayout('template_user')`)
4. Create separate actions, and forward the user based on it's permissions.

I'd go for the first :-)

Comment: thanks. most of them were in my mind too but i think i go for the first one too.